# camel http component 500

Tags: apache-camel

i was creating cxf/camel webservice and i've created for test code like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/user")
@ProduceMime({ "application/json" })
public String user(@FormParam("token") String token) throws Exception {

        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure(){
                from("direct:start").to("http://google.com");
            }
        });

        context.start();

        return token;

    }

}
```

Then i've compiled it and copied do FUSE ESB deploy folder. My webservice was installed, but when i opened URL with my webservice i got **500** response:

```
  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Failed to create route route17 at: >>> To[http://google.com] <<< in route: Route[[From[direct:start]] -> [To[http://google.com]]] because of Failed to resolve endpoint: http://google.com due to: No component found with scheme: http
Caused by:

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Failed to create route route17 at: >>> To[http://google.com] <<< in route: Route[[From[direct:start]] -> [To[http://google.com]]] because of Failed to resolve endpoint: http://google.com due to: No component found with scheme: http
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:108)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:323)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:206)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:209)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:152)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:184)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

additionally i have imported:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.component.http.*;
import org.apache.camel.component.http.helper.*;
```

on ESB i have turned on **camel-http**

what is wrong?

```
--------------
```

So i this what i wrote is wrong, is this code below should works right?

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/osgi/cxf-extension-osgi.xml" />

    <bean id="cxfSSO" class="com.esb.cxf.SSO" />
    <jaxrs:server id="sso" address="/ssocamel2">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="cxfSSO" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

      <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <endpoint id="endpointURL" uri="http://localhost:8080/SSO/?token=test"/>

        <route>
          <from uri="direct:start"/>
          <to uri="callRealWebService"/>
        </route>

      </camelContext>



</beans>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the camel-http feature. From the Fuse ESB console you can type:

```
features:install camel-http
```

And then after that you can install/start your bundle.

And as Ben says, what you are doing inside the rest service is totally wrong. You should setup Camel route once. If you want to call a http endpoint from Java code using Camel, then you do not need a route, but you can use a ProducerTemplate. See the Camel docs for more details.

Comment: OK, so i will try to do everythig in xml - is the code that i've added below `-----------` is right ? Cose i run this application and i don't see that it's workign... :(

Comment: @Clauslbsen I have same problem [take a look at my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248596/activemq-camel-can-not-use-to-uri-http), can you suggest me how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

couple of things, "No component found with scheme: http" means that you are missing the camel-http dependency in your bundle

next, you should setup your Camel context/routes once...not in a method call like this.

Comment: I will check the bundle, but as i remember i have camel-http in my bundle - i will check.  About second - as it is shown in Apache Camel website, i can use `from("direct:start")
  .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("http://myserver/orders/${header.orderId}"))
  .to("http://dummyhost");`. If i can use something like this, why i can't use it in any method?

Comment: from a method, you can call a route (template.send("direct:start", message), etc), not define the route itself...see http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html