# Activemq-camel: can not use <to uri="http://...">

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

I want help to solve this problem, the following code is in bean.xml gives me error

```
<camelContext id="activeContext1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:ThermalMap"/>
        <to uri="http://myhost:8161/Example?throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Error I get:

> org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[http://myhost:8161/Example?throwExceptionOnFailure=false] <<< in route: Route[[From[activemq:queue:ThermalMap]] -> [To[htt://myhost... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: htt://myhost:8161/Example?throwExceptionOnFailure=false due to: Cannot auto create component: http

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:** I edit my application in eclipse. I have manually added all jar files in `webcontent/WEB-INF/lib` folder. `Bean.xml` is the one define my application. I used `java` to write my `consumer()` and `processor()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have not placed [camel-http](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) component in classpath. If you are using maven then put the dependency of camel-http component in your pom and it shall work.

Comment: I don't use maven, I have placed camel-http-2.10.4.jar in class path

Comment: Even I place or not place camel-http-2.10.4.jar in class path I get same error.

Comment: @niren Please provide more details about application i.e. how do you run and set the classpath

Comment: can you please check my edited question. If you not understand please let me know.

Comment: In eclipse how are you running ? Have you created a class with main method to load the bean.xml or are you creating a war file and running that on tomcat using eclipse ?. This looks like a classpath issue. What the exception says is that Camel is not able to create the component that will allow http calls.

Comment: I have loaded `bean.xml` by this code `ApplicationContext springcontext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");` from `consumer()`. I used integrated tomcat 7.0 to execute my application from eclipse and as I said I put all jars in `webcontent/WEB-INF/lib` folder

Comment: I still think that there is an issue with classpath. Can you write the following piece of code in your application and check whether it executes or not : `Class.forName("org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpComponent")`.  If it executes without errors then it implies that your classpath is correctly setup and camel-http component is there in the applications classpath

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38803/discussion-between-hussain-pirosha-and-niren)